# Can I use a wildcard for a directory with a randomized numeric name?

Tags: windows, batch-file, wildcards

I am making a tool that is for editing the shortcuts for games in a Steam library, but the problem I face is that the shortcuts file path differs per user. In the path to the file, there is the users folder that is using what I can only assume is the Steam user ID. Here is an example path:

```
C:\Program Files\Steam\userdata\%STEAMID%\config\shortcuts.vdf
```

I would like to know if there is a wildcard or other variable I can use in a batch script that will "auto-detect" or open this path since it will differ per user. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am also open to using a VB script, I just prefer batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I would like to know if there is a wildcard or other variable I can use in a batch script that will "auto-detect" or open this path since
>   it will differ per user**

You can set two variables with one being the first part of the full path just before the point where the folder that's variable changes (i.e. `C:\Program Files\Steam\userdata`), and the second being the second part of the path just after the variable named folder (i.e. `config`).

You can then use two [FOR /D](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) loops with the first one referencing the first part path variable with a wildcard after it, and the second one to append the second part referencing the second part path variable. This will dynamically auto populate the variable named folders in between the first and second parts of the paths for you to iterate commands over accordingly.

---

> **Note:** *Save the below logic to a text document but rename it to give it a file extension of `.cmd` or `.bat`, and then double click on
>   it to run.*

**Batch Script**

```
@ECHO ON
SET SRC1=C:\Program Files\Steam\userdata
SET SRC2=config

FOR /D %%X IN ("%SRC1%\*") DO FOR /D %%Y IN ("%%X\%SRC2%\shortcuts.vdf") DO START "" "Notepad++.exe" "%%~Y"
::PAUSE
EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /D](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)
- [START](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Comment: That did it! To ensure the scripts consistency, I made several random test paths, and the script located and opened the VDF each time. Thank you for your collaboration @McDonald's